# ImageMagick convert generates an extra copy

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

I have a list of images in my folder of different sizes. When I do the following,

```
convert * -geometry '320x320' *
```

it re-sizes the images, however it also creates a duplicate of the original image. Is there an option which I can use so that it does not generate duplicates of the original image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageMagick's `mogrify` instead of its `convert` for multiple images:

```
mogrify -geometry 320x320 *
```

Or, if you really, really want to use `convert`:

```
for f in *.jpg; do convert "$f" -geometry 320x320 "$f"; done
```